# MFC keyboard shortcuts conflict with ribbon edit controls

Tags: mfc, keyboard-shortcuts, ribbon

When using a MFC ribbon based application, by default we get options to add keyboard short cuts for all our commands.  So for example, I might use 'p' to bring up the print preview dialog.  When I'm in a dialog, these commands are not active as you would expect, even if that dialog is not modal.  However, if I click into an edit control on the ribbon these commands remain active, so for the example given I could not type 'p' into my edit control.  A work-around is to add a modifier such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> but this makes the shortcut more awkward for my users.  Is it possible to change the message filter either for the ribbon as a whole, or for individual ribbon controls, such that they ignore keyboard shortcuts the same way a dialog does?

**Edit**  [Some feedback here from related thread on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2543196d-dc93-4c65-8be7-a56acdbef576/mfc-keyboard-shortcuts-conflict-with-ribbon-edit-controls?forum=vcgeneral#2543196d-dc93-4c65-8be7-a56acdbef576)